# Drop-down arrow and expand/collapse option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a really hard time trying to add 3 simple things to my current page:

- A visual cue like a sideways triangle to show if the list is currently collapsed or expanded
- Within the same structure (list + triangle) an extra dotted line treemap visual aid for a upcoming resources column like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brunorl/a5xk30gz/)
- A decent good working expand all and collapse all toggle like link/button. The "gueto" solution implemented was not approved as it does not always collapse all or expand all (*it really just toggle all div), the one below lacks consistency..

The sample: http://jsfiddle.net/brunorl/kL70z8ky/7/ :

```
/*toggle to expand/collapse all description items*/
$("a.listexpand").on('click', function () {
    $('div.descriptions').slideToggle(600).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Thanks a bunch, 
-b

Comment: If you want to expand all section and close or reopen for one in time, just create a extra class. addCLass('expand_all'); and then removeClass('active') if i understand a question. :)

Comment: One of these should work for you. Welcome to stack overflow.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-treeview/

Comment: Thanks for the inputs folks, but what I was looking for was a way to implement the 3 bullets above **within** my current structure and classes.